# get selected list option from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server-2012

i have to get select option list from my database

and for this my controller is

```
<?php
require_once 'connexion.php';

$sql = "select * from Motif";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

if ($stmt === false)
{
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors() , true));
}

$data = array();

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $data["id"] = $row['id'];
    $data["libelle"] = utf8_encode($row['libelle']);
    echo json_encode($data);
}

echo json_encode($data);
exit;
?>
```

and my html like this

```
<select id="rejetselect" class="form-control">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>

</select>
```

and to get values from database with ajax i did this code

```
var $select = $('#rejetselect');
$.ajax({
    url: 'motifRejet.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'libelle',
    success: function() {
        alert('good');

    },
    error: function() {
        alert('nooo');
    }

});
```

so after testing all this i can see my alert in good and in my console i can see the information that i got from database but i can't see it in my select option

Comment: Please add below code to your success function: `$("#rejetselect").val("Selectedvalue");` where SelectedValue is your database table value.

Comment: You won't see it in your select option because you haven't written any code to achieve this.